running a netsuite item fulfillment search with trying to return item info
I am trying to create a NetSuite saved search that searches for a certain Item Fulfillment and bring back the items (with internal id of the items) on it    This is the search I made ( both code and UI shown)
var transactionSearchObj = search.create({
   type: "transaction",
   filters:
   [
      ["internalid","anyof","3296363"], 
      "AND", 
      ["mainline","is","F"]
   ],
   columns:
   [
      search.createColumn({name: "mainline", label: "*"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "type", label: "Type"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "tranid", label: "Document Number"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "entity", label: "Name"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "account", label: "Account"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "amount", label: "Amount"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "item", label: "Item"}),
      search.createColumn({name: "quantity", label: "Quantity"}),
      search.createColumn({
         name: "internalid",
         join: "item",
         label: "Internal ID"
      })
   ]
});
var searchResultCount = transactionSearchObj.runPaged().count;
log.debug("transactionSearchObj result count",searchResultCount);
transactionSearchObj.run().each(function(result){
   // .run().each has a limit of 4,000 results
   return true;
});


The issue is, it brings back multiple results for each item on the IF.   I tried to change it to Mainline = true and that of course only brings back one line (the first item).  I wondered if there is some other kind of filter that I would need to set to allow me to only bring back the results that would pertain to the lines as they are on the item fulfillment.      Below is a screen shot to show the behavior as I am seeing it now.
     Notice the duplicates  (note i used the chrome addon to convert a saved search into code to get the below result and code.   In the end I will be putting it into javascript code but i can convert it to script if I had the saved search working correctly.

You are getting a line per gl entry. You should single things up by adding
,"AND", 
["cogs","is","F"]


awesome thanks.   That seeems like that was the trick.
